# Removing parent slug from URL on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

As the title states, I'd like to remove parent slugs from URLs for a particular post type: services.

Something that would change this:

```
http://demo.com/parent-service/child-service-1
http://demo.com/grand-parent-service/parent-service/child-service-2
http://demo.com/great-grand-parent-service/grand-parent-service/parent-service/child-service-3
etc
```

To something like this:

```
http://demo.com/child-service-1
http://demo.com/child-service-2
http://demo.com/child-service-3
etc
```

I'd rather not use an additional plugins to accomplish this. I'm currently delivering the CPT via a plugin, which also registers a custom taxonomy.

Comment: Does your custom post type need to be hierarchical? If not, set that to false and the URLs won't be hierarchical

Comment: yes, they do need to be hierarchical. this is mainly for archivial pages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a quick test, I was surprised to find that this works out of the box. That is, the canonical URI for a child post still has the parent in the path, but the child post works just as well without it (doesn't 404, doesn't redirect). As a result, it should just be a matter of filtering `post_type_link` to get this to work as you're asking! The following code should do just that:

```
function wpse_101072_flatten_hierarchies( $post_link, $post ) {
    if ( 'service' != $post->post_type )
        return $post_link;

    $uri = '';
    foreach ( $post->ancestors as $parent ) {
        $uri = get_post( $parent )->post_name . "/" . $uri;
    }

    return str_replace( $uri, '', $post_link );
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpse_101072_flatten_hierarchies', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Minor oversight. When I copied/pasted the code you gave, it didn't work, then I noticed the lack of the 's' on the post type. Boom! Everything is working. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad you caught that and that it worked as desired! FYI, convention in WordPress is to have your post type singular. "post", "page", etc.

Comment: It doesn't work for pages

what shoul I change for having instead domain-name.com/parent/child/sub-child/ domain-name.com/sub-child/

or instead domain-name.com/parent/child/ domain-name.com/child/

Comment: I am also looking for something similar. How do I use this code? Do I copy it as-is into function.php ? or should I replace any value with the custom post type that I use. Any help ....