# How to remove parent slugs from child pages permalinks?

Tags: permalinks

I remove them all right, but when I actually try to go to a page, there is a 404 error.

The code I have used ( variation of [Removing Parent Page(s) from Permalink](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/182006/removing-parent-pages-from-permalink#answer-313280) )

```
function my_pages_permalink( $link, $post_id) {
    $slugname = get_post_field( 'post_name', $post_id, 'display' );
    $slugname = $slugname."/";
    $link = untrailingslashit( home_url($slugname) ) . '.html';
    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'page_link', 'my_pages_permalink', 10, 3 );
```

What else should be done? Some add_rewrite_rule? What it may be like?

Comment: Did you flush the permalinks after adding your code?

Comment: Sure, I did flush it.

Comment: @PatJ It seems WordPress somehow does not know or understand that a new permalink structure is set. Since new links (without parent slugs) are right in their proper places in resulting page code, but clicking on them does not lead to the corresponding pages, but to 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

To remove parent slugs from child pages' permalinks in WordPress and avoid the 404 error, you'll need to modify your code and add some rewrite rules.

1. First, modify your code to remove the parent slug from the child page's permalink:

```php
function my_pages_permalink($link, $post) {
    if ($post->post_parent) {
        $parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
        $link = trailingslashit(home_url($parent->post_name)) . $post->post_name . '/';
    }
    return $link;
}
add_filter('page_link', 'my_pages_permalink', 10, 2);
```

This code checks if the page has a parent and constructs the permalink accordingly.

2. Next, you need to add rewrite rules to handle the modified permalinks. Add the following code to your theme's `functions.php` or create a custom plugin:

```php
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
```

These rewrite rules will interpret the modified permalink structure.

3. After adding the rewrite rules, you need to flush the rewrite rules for them to take effect. You can do this by visiting the "Settings" > "Permalinks" page in your WordPress admin and simply clicking the "Save Changes" button.

With these modifications, the parent slugs should be removed from child pages' permalinks, and you should no longer encounter the 404 error. This solution works by rewriting the URLs to match the new structure you defined in your `my_pages_permalink` function.

Comment: Your function + add_rewrite_rule does not seem to remove slugs. I have tried your add_rewrite_rule separately with my function, but it has not worked either. Maybe it has to be not an add_rewrite_rule, but some setting some variables somehow "by hand"?